# Why is Ubuntu 15.10 drastically slower than Windows 10?

Tags: boot, 15.10

I have a PC that is dual booting W10 and Ubuntu 15.10 and I am noticing a drastic difference in speed between the two.  I was told that Linux is more efficient than Windows and should run faster.  Everything from slow boot times to slow application loading and page switching.  I have Dual Quad core 3.2Ghz machine overclocked to 5.4Ghz with 12 Gigs of ram so the PC shouldnt be the problem.  Any suggestions? I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general so all help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a much more vague question than you might be thinking. What sort of hardware and drivers are you using? You can start by installing, if needed `inxi` and then running `inxi -Fxz` from the terminal and editing your question with the output from that command.

Comment: Gnome uses memory in an odd way that makes it faster on devices with less ram but slower on devices with more ram. Try a distro like Xubuntu or Mint and it should be much faster on a 12GB-RAM machine.

Answer (score 3):

Those 2 operating system are impossible to compare. They are fundamentally different.

To compare: my Ubuntu has an SSD for the main parts of Ubuntu (/), a re-install is done in under 20 minutes. Booting takes less than 10 seconds (13-ish if there is a filesystem check). I have no problems with speed. Beta versions of Ubuntu tend to be difficult to use on my system (even though my system is no longer that new I always have a bit of problems with hardware).

What you can do is check on the Ubuntu side...

1. the boot process with [bootchart](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting). It is native to Ubuntu that uses systemd. Main issues for boot to take longer than needed are not correctly configured hardware. Main issue with those would be your wireless: if the wireless connection errors out it will retry several times and then move on.
2. the running system. Commands useful are "top","htop","powertop".  All of these show memory usage and things related to it. Check if something is hogging your system.

> I was told that Linux is more efficient than Windows and should run faster.

To me it is but that comment has problems.

"Efficient" is a matter of knowing what to do when you want something done. That is something that takes time to get to learn. "Faster". Yes in my opinion it is. At work my older notebook boots a lot quicker with Ubuntu (14.04) than my newer desktop does using Windows 7.